# Como mantener la cultura y utf-8 en blazor server cuando se publica en app service de Azure

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0

Hola tengo una aplicación en blazor server la cual muestra cifras en colones , cuando la app la levanto con Visual Studio todo se visualiza correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo cuando la publico en el app service de azure algo pasa que no se muestra como debe ser:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para establecer la cultura utilizo este código en el Program.cs :

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CR");
CultureInfo cultureUI= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");

//culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

//cultureUI.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUI;

//System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");

//System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es");

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;
const string urlconnectionString = "RestConnection";
const string storage = "Storage";
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

Es alguna configuración que debo realizar en el app service de azure o un error en la programación??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno luego de una larga busqueda me di cuenta que efectivamente era una asunto de programación. Hay que configurar la cultura en el Program.cs:

```
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CR");
CultureInfo cultureUI= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");


System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureUI;

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    List<CultureInfo> cultures = new List<CultureInfo> { culture,cultureUI};
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestCulture(culture);
    options.SupportedCultures = cultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
});


app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! Ahora recuerda esperar alrededor de 24 horas para aceptar la respuesta, de este modo apoyarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de respuestas resueltas). Saludos y que sigan los éxitos en el desarrollo :D